# Using Office UI Fabric JS with SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I would like to know if I should  install nodeJs to use Office UI Fabric JS compenents ?

Answer (score 3):

No its not needed to install Node js.

You can simply reference the Office fabric components from CDN or download it locally and then upload in your SP environment like site assets or style library.

You can add the below references in the `<head>` section of master page or inside script editor or page layout etc.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.components.min.css">
<script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Reference - [Office UI Fabric js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js)

[Office fabric components list](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js/blob/master/ghdocs/COMPONENTSLIST.md)

For example, if you want to use Fabric UI button, you can use the below html:

```
<button class="ms-Button">
  <span class="ms-Button-label">Create Account</span>
</button>
```

After that, you can instantiate it as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ButtonElements = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-Button");
    for(var i = 0; i < ButtonElements.length; i++) {
        new fabric['Button'](ButtonElements[i], function() {
            // Insert Event Here
        });
    }
</script>
```

Reference - [Fabric UI Button](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js/blob/master/ghdocs/components/Button.md)

Comment: but could I use also components ? not only styles ?

Comment: Yes, check the link - https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js/blob/master/ghdocs/COMPONENTSLIST.md , you can use these components. Check updated answer

Comment: No NodeJS, No SPFx, No React: https://365csi.nl/toolkit/iconator.html uses FabricJS. Pure ES6 code (so also No Internet Explorer.. this is my Chrome play & learn project)

Comment: thank you, I would inderstand what means fabric['Bouton']

Comment: cool, could you please mark it as answer :)